# Should I specify users when using Maven with Tomcat?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I'm started to learn Maven and now trying to integrate it with web app that I was worked on.

I'm using Tomcat 7 and in most examples I've seen people specify user on `tomcat-users.xml` in `${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/` directory and then modify `pom.xml` and `settings.xml` for maven like so:

**tomcat-users.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>
  <user username="user" password="123456" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"></user>
</tomcat-users>
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<build>
...
<plugins>
...
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>
<server>apache-tomcat7</server>
<url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
<path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
<username>user</username>
<password>123456</password>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

**settings.xml:**

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
    <interactiveMode>true</interactiveMode>
    <usePluginRegistry>false</usePluginRegistry>
    <offline>false</offline>
 <servers>
      <server>
        <id>apache-tomcat7</id>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>123456</password>
      </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

So my questions are:

1. Should tomcat-users be specified every time for every project ? Can I omit it ?
2. If I can't then is it just needed for security reasons ?
3. Also I read that it's a bad practice to combine roles such `manager-script` and `manager-gui` in one user - so for two users how to accordingly modify files listed above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purpose of this plugin is to be able to deploy/run/test your web projects in a tomcat web container for automated tests. The plugin will launch the tomcat server before your tests begin and stops when they are over. Given the nature of usage of this web container, security may not a prime concern and you may skip specifying users and just rely on the defaults as described here : [Tomcat7 Maven Plugin usage](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Hope this helps.